Custom TimeSeries in Grafana
My goal is to make timeseries chart in Grafana, that shows a line from SQL Agent Job starting point to the point of time job start + duration (e.g. line from 10:00 till 10:30 with value 1).
There are two simple metrics which I get from Prometheus: job_timestamp, job_duration.
How can I make a desired timeline chart based on these metrics?
I have tried Google without any success.

Assuming job_timestamp has timestamp as value in seconds, job_duration has duration as value in seconds and both of them are unique, you can use following query to get desired result:
vector(1)
 and timestamp(vector(1)) > scalar(job_timestamp)
 and timestamp(vector(1)) < scalar(job_timestamp + job_duration)


Hi, Thank you!
I have made formula as you suggested:
vector(1) and timestamp (vector(1))>=scalar(job_status_run_timestamp{host="xxx-yyy-000", job_exec_id="3161124"}) and timestamp(vector(1))<=sum(job_status_run_timestamp{host="xxx-yyy-000", job_exec_id="3161124"} or job_status_run_duration{host="xxx-yyy-000", job_exec_id="3161124"})
I got a line  on chart (in Prom Query at least), but starting point and duration  is not equal to real information.  I guess the start point is an issue with time format probably as well as duration. Maybe you can notice something wrong in my solution?

Prometheus stores everything in UTC. If your data is in local time, you might have issue with that. You'll need to figure needed offset and add/subtract it manually. @Alexey

Can you suggest why this query works in Prometheus console but nothing in Grafana?

@Alexey, no. Use Inspect > Query in context menu of panel to check details. But there should not be any difference.
